# Recursively find the correct order of reads

Tags: python

I've some trouble with this task for some hours, and I'm simply stuck at what to do.

First I need a function that takes a dictionary argument and then returns the key associated with the largest value. This is what I've tried:

```
def findKeyForLargestValue(d):
    maxKey = ''
    maxValue = 0

    for name in d:
        for subName in d[name]:
            d = d[name][subName]

    if d > maxValue:
        maxKey = subName

    return maxKey
```

Then I need to make a function that takes a string 'name' and a dictionary 'overlaps' as arguments which must return a list of reads names in order in which they represent the genomic sequence:

`def findOrder(name, overlaps):

readOrder = []`

I need to use the function findKeyForLargestValue(d) inside the other function. I need to use base case which should return [name] and recursive case which should return [name] + findOrder(nextName) where nextName is the name of the read that has the largest overlap to the right end of the current read (name).

Any help is appreciated because I'm really lost. Not even sure that the code for findKeyForLargestValue is correct

Comment: For your first problem: `import operator; d = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}; sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))`, returns a list of tuples, ordered by key: `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]`. Or better, just `max` instead of sorted (see mgilson's answer).

Answer (score 2):

The "simple" answer is to use the builtin [`max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function:

```
from operator import itemgetter
def findKeyForLargestValue(d):
    key,value = max(d.items(),key=itemgetter(1))
    return key
```

As noted in the comments, if memory is *really* a concern and you're using python2.x, then you could use `d.iteritems()` instead of `d.items()`.  I generally use `d.items()` since it will work on python2.x and python3.x without modification (in this context) and the additional memory associated with `d.items()` as opposed to `d.iteritems()` is nearly always irrelevant for any work that I've done.

---

If you're confused about `itemgetter`, see the following:

```
def func(seq):
    return seq[1]

#`func(x)` will return the same thing that `itemgetter(1)(x)` returns
# for any indexible object `x`
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Or just `return max(d.items(),key=itemgetter(1))[0]`. Also, it may be beneficial to use `iteritems()` instead of `items()`.

Comment: @A.R.S. -- I've never really seen the fascination with `iteritems` -- especially in contexts where you don't know that OP is using python2.x.  Really, if you can store the dictionary in memory already, storing an additional list of it's key/value pairs is going to be insignificant in 99% of cases ...

Comment: +1 - I was going to suggest `max(d, key=lambda x: max(d[x][y] for y in d[x]))` in case there were multiple nested keys with different names, but I may have been reading it wrong (and that isn't pretty anyway :) ).

Comment: @KajaKjaer -- The second part of your question is pretty unclear to me.  I don't understand what the `findOrder` function is supposed to do...

Answer (score 0):

First off, your indentation is incorrect.

```
def findKeyForLargestValue(d):
    for name in d:
        for subName in d[name]:
            d = d[name][subName]

            if d > maxValue: #Look at the indentation here
                 maxKey = subName #And here

    return maxKey
```